# Possible to put HTML annotations on PDF?

Tags: pdf

I know that we can now put text, links and videos..but can we put HTML as annotation as well?

If there's a SDK, please point me to it as well.

I have tried to search as much as possible but couldn't find anything on it.

Updated: okay, here are more details. I'm creating a script to create a PDF from an image, and at the same time have to place annotations on top of the image. When the person click the annotation, the HTML will be shown. I understand there are link annotations and shape annotation, but what I'm looking for is the ability to place HTML markup/codes in the annotation. For example, i would be able to design a simple form or style some text or even a embed YouTube video.

I hope I'm clear.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you clarify what tool or programming language you are using? I can tell you how you can do it in Java if you want.

Comment: Hey akshay, I'm open to all languages. I'm more concern about the feasibility of it. Thanks for your reply!

Comment: You misunderstand me, do you already have the PDF created? If yes, then you need something for PDF editing, if not, then you need something from scratch. That is why I asked, can you please describe in more detail what is your task, what do you have now? Still for your convinience, I am posting some PDF annotations code as answer, if you dont like the answer, let me know.

Comment: Thanks for your prompt reply, akshay! I have furnished more details in my question.

Comment: Thats simple task. Unfortunately I don't have much time now, is it ok, if I give you code in 3-4 hours? Adding a java method to add image. String input is the image as String.

Answer (score 0):

Here goes a very basic sample code : Please add Itext jar in your project

Code :

```
import com.itextpdf.text.Document;
import com.itextpdf.text.PageSize;
import com.itextpdf.text.Rectangle;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfWriter;
import com.itextpdf.text.Image;
//input is image in String format
   public void createfromimage(String input){
        Document document = new Document(PageSize.A4.rotate());
        document.setMargins(0,0,0,0);        

        String output = "C:/Users/username/Downloads/text.pdf";
        try {
            FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(output);
            PdfWriter pdfWriter = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, fileOutputStream);
            Image image = Image.getInstance(input);
            document.setPageSize(new Rectangle(image.getWidth(),image.getHeight()));
            document.open();
            pdfWriter.open();
            document.add(image);
            document.close();
            pdfWriter.close();
        } catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

You can add annotations in above way, and for Link annotations, refer to link below :

https://pdfbox.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/pdfbox/pdmodel/interactive/annotation/PDAnnotationLink.html

please note, this is just a simple example.